# onChange event is not working on my Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Hi i want to do something when mi select box changes, i have something like this:

```
function Task(){
    const prints = (e) =>{
        console.log("it prints");
    }

    const prints2 = (e) =>{
        console.log("it prints2");
    }

return (
     <select onChange={prints} onClick={prints2} name="subject">
        {subjectsContext.subjects.map((aSubject)=>(
            <option value={aSubject.idsubject}>
                {aSubject.subjectname}
            </option>
        )
        )}
        </select>
)
}
```

subjects is a list that i have, when i put onClick instead of onChange it works fine, but when i put onChange it dont works when i select a option, it just dont trigger the prints function, why?

Comment: For me your code appears to work as is. It just doesn't call your onChange until after you have selected a different option from you select, but I think that is to be expected.

Comment: Yes, i saw and is it, but if i have just one option for the moment? The onChange wont trigger, i guess i have to use the onClick that it triggers just clicking.

Comment: On possible solution could be to have a default "please choose an option" option, so the user must pick something other than the default, thus triggering the onChange.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event (e) to the function as a parameter, try this:

```
function Task() {
  const prints = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log('it prints');
  };

  const prints2 = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log('it prints2');
  };

  return (
    <select
      onChange={(e) => prints(e)}
      onClick={(e) => prints2(e)}
      name='subject'
    >
      {subjectsContext.subjects.map((aSubject) => (
        <option value={aSubject.idsubject}>{aSubject.subjectname}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Also - consider adding a `key` attribute to you option as you're mapping trough it and creating duplicate elements in the DOM, I assume this is a react app so it might cause errors.

Edit: ... And you don't need the onClick here, you won't even get an event so simply remove it.